# Javascript large Number parsing

Tags: javascript, view, couchbase, couchbase-view

I am using a Couchbase view to emit a few records. Among those records, there is one record which is 19 digit long. When Couchbase view (written in javascript) pulls those record, it rounds off the record into smaller one and loses precision.

-7092643922943239825 is actual number
but when retrieved from below view:

```
function(doc, meta) {
if (doc.docType == 'xyz') {
    if (doc.source) {
            if (doc.source != null) {
                emit([doc.valA, doc.valB,  loc], 1);
            }
    } 
}
```

The output I get is:

```
[ **-7092643922943240000, 1523365218128317200**, "abc" ]
```

I was expecting:

```
"doc": {
  "valA": 1523365218128317302,
  "valB": -7092643922943239825
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well ... `1523365218128317302 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and `-7092643922943239825 < Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` so, they can't safely be represented as Numbers without loss of precision - have you tried `-7092643922943240000n` and `1523365218128317200n`?

Comment: adding "n" with actual number, allows to get required output. but since i am pulling this data from DB, i can't actually change original number to have "n" suffix.

Comment: Oh, so the server is sending those values as numbers not strings ... you can't fix the server?

Comment: it won't be straight forward. since these documents are already present in DB now. we won't be able to change datatype of existing documents , without re-running entire process.

Comment: so, the DB stores those values as a numeric value - is it a 64bit integer?

Comment: its a long datatype in the model

Comment: not familiar with couchbase enough to help, sorry

Comment: Have you tried to immediately use BigInt(number_from_server) when getting it? It's similar to ...n, but in order to append an "n" you'd first have to parse the number, where the loss already happens. Using the proper conversation method above might circumvent the step where the precision-loss happens?

Comment: yes, i tried using BigInt as well but got same result. i used emit([bigInt(doc.valA), doc.valB,  loc], 1);     I have also used parseInt(). valueOf() and toString() but nothing does the work. it seems like value already comes changed , when view is executed.

Comment: Related discussion on Couchbase Forum: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-view-rounds-off-the-long-value-in-emit/34370

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have cross posted this question, please refer to a detailed discussion concerning your issue as posted to https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-view-rounds-off-the-long-value-in-emit/34370 (the link was previously referenced by [dnault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611819/dnault))